# Is it possible to define a Jasmine spec inside a function and still have beforeEach apply to it?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a lot of tests which are virtually the same. In the interests of DRY and scanability I'd like to abstract the tests into a single function and then call that function with a few parameters. The function would then call `it` and add the spec to the suite.

It seems to work, except the specs don't get run in the same way as the other specs and `beforeEach` is not called before the specs defined in the common function.

```
define(['modules/MyModule','jasmine/jasmine'], function(MyModule) {

    describe('myModule', function() {

        function commonTests(params) {
            it('should pass this test OK', function() {
                expect(true).toBe(true);
            });

            it('should fail because module is undefined', function() {
                expect(module[params.method]()).toBe('whatever');
            });
        }

        var module;

        beforeEach(function() {
            module = new MyModule();
        });

        describe('#function1', function() {
            commonTests({
                method: 'function1'
            });
        });

        describe('#function2', function() {
            commonTests({
                method: 'function2'
            });
        });

    });

});
```

Is there any way of doing this and maintaining the functionality of `beforeEach` and `afterEach`?

**UPDATE:**

Looks like I got my example wrong, sorry. Here's the case that fails:

```
define(['modules/MyModule'], function(MyModule) {

    function commonTests(params) {
        it('will fail because params.module is undefined', function() {
            expect(typeof params.module).toBe('object');
            expect(typeof params.module[params.method]).toBe('function');
        });

        it('has a few tests in here', function() {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    }


    describe('MyModule', function() {

        var module;

        beforeEach(function() {
            module = new MyModule();
        });

        describe('#function1', function() {
            commonTests({
                module: module,
                method: 'function1'
            });
        });

        describe('#function2', function() {
            commonTests({
                module: module,
                method: 'function2'
            });
        });

    });
});
```

I think it fails because the value of `module` is preserved as part of the call to `commonTests` instead of always using the current value of `module` as in the first example. I'll post my solution when I get there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Andreas for pointing out that my first example actually worked! The final solution I'm using is very similar:

```
define(['modules/MyModule'], function(MyModule) {

    var module;

    function commonTests(params) {
        it('will not fail because module is shared', function() {
            expect(typeof module).toBe('object');
            expect(typeof module[params.method]).toBe('function');
        });

        it('has a few tests in here', function() {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    }


    describe('MyModule', function() {

        beforeEach(function() {
            module = new MyModule();
        });

        describe('#function1', function() {
            commonTests({
                method: 'function1'
            });
        });

        describe('#function2', function() {
            commonTests({
                method: 'function2'
            });
        });

    });
});
```

Although if you needed to have the ability to pass in `module` as an argument to `commonTests` you would have to take a slightly different approach and have a different function for each `it` block:

```
define(['modules/MyModule'], function(MyModule) {

    var module;

    function commonTest1(params) {
        expect(typeof module).toBe('object');
        expect(typeof module[params.method]).toBe('function');
    }

    function commonTest2(params) {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    }


    describe('MyModule', function() {

        beforeEach(function() {
            module = new MyModule();
        });

        describe('#function1', function() {

            it('will not fail because module is shared', function() {
                commonTest1({ method: 'function1' });
            });

            it('has a few tests in here', function() {
                commonTest2({ method: 'function1' });
            });

        });

        describe('#function2', function() {

            it('will not fail because module is shared', function() {
                commonTest1({ method: 'function2' });
            });

            it('has a few tests in here', function() {
                commonTest2({ method: 'function2' });
            });

        });

    });
});
```

This way the executions of the functions containing the common tests is delayed until after beforeEach has run its callback.

Answer (score 0):

yes, this scenario works fine for us. We use chutzpah to run the the tests in our gated checkins and our tests would fail without the `afterEach` functions.

But the `define` line looks like `require.js`. We had several problems with that ...
I suppose that `MyModule` is `undefined` or not defined as expected. Have you tried to set a breakpoint in the `beforeEach` method to see if it was called and what value `MyModule` has? How are you calling the tests?

When I run your code without the `define` line the `beforeEach` function gets called 4x - as expected. Btw I used chutzpah.console.exe to call the tests.

Edit:

Yeah, now I can reproduce the problem on my PC. And it's much more clear to me.
At the beginning `module` is undefined as every variable is undefined first. Then you register your functions in jasmine using `beforeEach` and `describe`. Jasmine starts with evaluating

```
function() {
    commonTests({
        module: module,
        method: 'function1'
    });
}
```

which was passed to the first `describe`. At the line `module: module` JS copies the *reference* of `var module` to the new objects property `module` and this references `undefined` so far. When the `beforeEach` callback gets called it changes the reference of the `var module` to the correct value but the wrong reference has already been copied ...

I tried to move `var module` above `function commonTests` and used that variable in the tests instead of `params.module` and they pass as expected. I don't know if that is an option in your environment but I hope it it helps.

Greets,
Andreas

Comment: Interesting, well you are right of course: it is require.js. The thing is I know MyModule is getting loaded OK because there are other tests that use it that aren't in `commonTests` (which I left out for brevity) and they pass just fine.

When I run the debugger in `commonTests` and check the value of `module` it is `undefined`. It has the correct value in tests outside of `commonTests`...

Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: I suppose that the other tests are located in the two `describe` calls at the bottom, right? I remember that I've read something about `var` scopes in JS. In some cases the variables defined with `var` in functions are available only after the `var` statement. If that's the case here you would try to access the global `module` (which doesn't exist) in `commonTests`. Perhaps you can try to move the `var module;` and the `beforeEach` to the top of the surrounding `describe`.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I had a look and compared the example to my code and it was slightly different. I've posted an update in the question...

Comment: That's basically what I've ended up doing. If it's absolutely necessary to pass in the module in the params there's another solution which I'll write up shortly. Thanks!